# HIgh Score system in pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Here is the code to a python snake game, I've tried to use modules shelve and pickle to no success after trying to incorporate them as seen in other questions on the site. Do you know a way to include these modules or others so that the high score would be printed in the terminal under the score. As of now the score is printed every time the snake bites his tail and you close the messagebox, then right away a new game starts. The goal would be that the highscore prints as the same time as the score. I've left out some of the code as shown by "[...]" If you want to see other parts of it i'll be happy to show it...

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
import random
import math
from tkinter import messagebox 


[…]

def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width=500
    rows=20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake ((0,255,0),(10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(255,0,0))
    flag = True

    clock=pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color = (255,0,0))

        for x in range(len(s.body)):
            if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos,s.body[x+1:])): 
                print('Score: ', len(s.body))
                message_box('You Lost!', 'Try again')
                s.reset((10,10))
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean. The way I handled the high score in my first Snake game was something like this:

1. Import latest high score from a file in the project folder on my computer to a variable self.high_score.
2. Have a separate variable self.score that handles the score for the current game.
3. Print both variables during the game, where `self.score += 1` when the snake eats a snack, and self.high_score stays constant throughout the game.
4. When the game ends (the snake dies), a check is made to see `if self.score > self.high_score`. If that is the case, `self.high_score = self.score` and the number in the local file on my computer is updated with this new high score.

With this method the game can remember the high score even if you close the game and starts over another day.

Comment: Do you know how I could implement that tot the script ? What module can I use to create the file and then check the contents ? and how can I make my `self.score` variable from the len of the list s.body that is urgently how I show a score ?

Comment: Any Excel module will work. You simply create Excel file as usual and write a 0 in any cell. Then in beginning of the code you set your high score variable to whatever that cell is.

Comment: You set self.score += 1 at the place where you detect if the snake ate a snack.